# Почему библиотека Okhttp не работает на версиях api меньше 21?

Tags: android, okhttp

Я использую библиотеку Okhttp и на api >=21 работает, но на android 4.4 выдаёт ошибку.

```
try {
        result = response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Ошибка в строке: `result = response.body().string();`

```
Process: com.example.dander.tutdobro, PID: 4022
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:683)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:355)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:221)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1Codec.java:466)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:449)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1.read(CacheInterceptor.java:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipAll(Util.java:175)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.discard(Util.java:157)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1.close(CacheInterceptor.java:202)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:469)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:469)
    at okio.InflaterSource.close(InflaterSource.java:127)
    at okio.GzipSource.close(GzipSource.java:182)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:469)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:110)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:177)
    at com.example.dander.tutdobro.fragment.NewsFragment$4$2.run(NewsFragment.java:259)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 18:12:28.896 690-726/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.example.dander.tutdobro (com.example.dander.tutdobro/.MainActivity)
```

Comment: Проверяйте правильность подключеного  пакета, возможно студиа подключила не тот класс.

Comment: Но как тогда работает на других версиях андроида, проблема ведь только с api <21

Comment: @ВасяПупкин все работает на API 14+. Показывай больше кода, чтобы тебе помогли.

Comment: Нельзя работать с сетью в главном (UI) потоке. Выносите запрос в отдельный поток.

Answer (score 3):

У вас же банальный `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Вот тут ищите проблему:
`com.example.dander.tutdobro.fragment.NewsFragment$4$2.run(NewsFragment.java:259)`

Версии Android тут совсе ни при чем, `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` существует с 4.0.

Comment: Строка 259 - это result = response.body().string(); Про версию заговорил потому, что ошибка только ниже 21 апи. Но вот почему такая ошибка ведь это не основной поток